# Classifying abelian groups up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> List all abelian groups (up to isomorphism) of the given orders:
>   a) $144$, b) $600$

a) For order $144$, I feel confident with this one so far:

- $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{36}$ Elementary divisors: $2^2,6^2$. Invariant factors: $144$.
- $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6$. Elementary divisors: $2^2,6,6$. Invariant factors: $6,24$.
- $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{36}$. Elementary divisors: $2,2,6^2$. Invariant factors: $2,72$.
- $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6$. Elementary divisors: $2,2,6,6$. Invariant factors: $12,12$.

Therefore, we have

- $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{36} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{144}$
- $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \cong \mathbb{Z}_{6} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{25}$
- $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{36} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{72}$
- $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \cong \mathbb{Z}_{12} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{12}$

b) For order $600$, I am not so sure with this one:

- $\mathbb{Z}_{100} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6$ Elementary divisors: $10^2,6$. Invariant factors: $600$.
- $\mathbb{Z}_{10} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{10} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6$. Elementary divisors: $10,10,6$. Invariant factors: $10,60$.

Thus,

- $\mathbb{Z}_{100} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \cong \mathbb{Z}_{600}$
- $\mathbb{Z}_{10} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{10} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \cong \mathbb{Z}_{10} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{60}$

I feel confident with part a, but with part b I feel it's incomplete.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fundamental theorem on finite abelian groups? (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_abelian_group#Classification)

Comment: For order 144, see https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=GxUmU76FMtCCogSM4oDoAw&url=http://wwwp.cord.edu/faculty/ahendric/2011Fall325/practicesolns5.pdf&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHsCrwqPYsCh0BEib1_sJ2cg7Xx6A&sig2=9ICI4H3Vlp_FQFjdvDzC2w, and for order 600, see https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=aBUmU88P0NugBKe3gcAD&url=http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~m31x13/M31%2520HW%25206%2520Solutions.pdf&cd=2&ved=0CCkQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNE85zgwfVlHRjneY-QMBEDz2ryGjw&sig2=ssJ6baIq5HCkP5SFo2b7Dg

Comment: Also: 4*6 equals 24, not 25

Comment: glacier: Please do not delete your original question and 100% of your posted work. I've rolled back the edit to the pre-deleted version.

Comment: @amWhy I had deleted it because it was all wrong to me. What's wrong with erasing my own incorrect work?

Comment: Well, it's just frustrating for those who answer questions because it renders our posts meaningless to those visiting the question.

Comment: $10^2 = 2^2\times 5^2$, $6 = 2 \times 3$. For groups of order $600$, then, list the prime factors of $600 = 2^3\cdot 3\cdot 5^2$. And then use the useful fact I've included in my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last $$\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_6\times \mathbb Z_6$$ has order 288. I assume that instead of $\mathbb Z_4$ you meant $\mathbb Z_2$.

Also, $$\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_{36}\not \cong \mathbb Z_{144}$$ since $\gcd(4, 36) = 4$.

I make use of the fact that $$\mathbb Z_{mn} \cong \mathbb Z_m \times \mathbb Z_n\;\;\text{if and only if}\;\;\gcd(m, n) = 1$$

$$\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \not \cong \mathbb{Z}_{6} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{24}$$
because $\gcd(4, 6) = 2 \neq 1$.

$$\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \not\cong \mathbb{Z}_{12} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{12}$$ because $\gcd(2, 6) = 2 \neq 1$.

Also, $3\mid 144,\;6\mid 144,\; 8\mid 144,\; 16\mid 144$...

$$\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{36} \not \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{72}$$ since $\gcd(2, 36) = 2\neq 1$.

The prime factorization of $144$ is given by: $$144 = 2^43^2$$

Comment: "...if and only if $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ ohh I just forgot about that!! :|

Comment: Also, you used $\times$ instead of $\oplus$. Are they the same? My textbook uses the symbol $\oplus$ and my class was trying to be consistent with the textbook.

Comment: Yes, $\times, $\otimes$ are often used to denote the direct product/sum. So my use of $\times$ is meant to convey the direct sum in this case.

Comment: In one part of the answer, you typed "$$\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \cong \mathbb{Z}_{12} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{12}$$ because $\gcd(2, 6) = 2 \neq 1$." You probably mean to say "$\not\cong$"?

Comment: Based on the factorization of $144 = 2^4 3^2$, I got the relation  \begin{align}\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}_{144} \end{align} because $\gcd(2,3) = 1$. Elementary divisors are $2^4, 3^2$ and the invariant factor is $144$.

Comment: I believe I can also do the same for $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_9$ because $\gcd(2,9) = 1$. Similarly, I can do $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_9$, $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_9$, and $\mathbb{Z}_{16} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_9$.

Comment: Yes you can, glacier!